# How fix remember in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

The picture shows the code and logs
For some reason
`startDate` and `endDate` not recreated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to remember the input dates? You already have them in the composable param `input`.

You are getting different output because value in `input` has changed and has triggered recomposition, while in `startDate` and `endDate` you already have rememebered state from previous recomposition. On the next recomposition, the remember block won't be called, because the result already exists in the cache of the composer.

Here is what you need to improve in this code:

1. Remember the formatter, it's being recreated each recomposition.
2. Don't remember the `starDate` and `endDate` from `input` object
3. Format the dates only once, and remember that result instead, in case something else triggeres the recomposition.